# How to get a stable result from a weighting scale?

Tags: c#, serial-port

I have a project where I have to received the output from a weighing machine into computer and then cache in my software.

The brand of this scale is fairbank scales

model:70-2455-4w/431

Manual: perkinsscale.com/files/benchscales/manual1.pdf

Based on the manual I listed above, my thought for retrieving the data from the scale is that send and hex code to the scale and grab the information it response. I already have a code to receive the output, but I didn't get the exacted result all the time. Sometimes I got truncated result. For example, instead of showing me 150.15 LB, it showed 15 Lb or .15 LB. Moreover, sometimes I couldn't receive any data from it. It would just show me a blank result. What I need is that whenever I run the code, it would return me the exacted same number showing on the scale. The code I used is listed below:

Can anyone help me out?

```
using System;
using System.IO.Ports;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Collections;
using System.Threading;

namespace PortDataReceived
{
    class PortData
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                char CarriageReturn = (char)0x0D;
                string final =  CarriageReturn.ToString(); 
                SerialPort mySerialPort = new SerialPort("COM3");
                mySerialPort.BaudRate = 9600;
                mySerialPort.Parity = Parity.Odd;
                mySerialPort.StopBits = StopBits.Two;
                mySerialPort.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(1252);
                mySerialPort.DataBits = 7;
                mySerialPort.Handshake = Handshake.None;
                mySerialPort.ReadTimeout = 12000;
                mySerialPort.WriteTimeout = 5000;
                mySerialPort.DtrEnable = true;
                mySerialPort.RtsEnable = true;
                while (true)
                {
                    mySerialPort.Open();
                    mySerialPort.Write(final+"\r\n");
                    mySerialPort.DataReceived += new
                       SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(DataReceivedHandler);
                    Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue...");
                    Console.WriteLine();
                    Console.ReadKey();
                }
                mySerialPort.Close();
            }
            catch (System.IO.IOException e)
            {
                if (e.Source != null)
                    Console.WriteLine("IOException source: {0}", e.Source);
                throw;
            }
        }

        private static void DataReceivedHandler(
                            object sender,
                            SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            SerialPort sp = (SerialPort)sender;
            string indata = sp.ReadExisting();
            int i = sp.BytesToRead;
            indata = " " + indata + " ";
            if((indata.IndexOf(" "+"kg"+" ")>=0)||(indata.IndexOf(" "+"lb"+" ")>=0))
            {
                 Console.WriteLine("Data Received:");
                 Console.Write(indata);
                 Console.ReadKey();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please fix formatting of your code, it hurts in the eyes. (no empty lines...)

Comment: This is certainly bogus: ´double i = sp.BytesToRead;´

Comment: You should read **enough** bytes from the esrial port. for example: try to read until a newline is received or whatever the device uses to mark 'End of transmission'

Comment: As @DrKoch said, the `DataReceivedHandler` will trigger at *some point* when the port receives data. It might be triggered with part of a message, or all the message. You need to handle looking for the whatever the balance uses to mark the end of a reading *and then* parse everything your received up to that point.

Comment: Thank you guys, it is very clear! Sorry for the bad format.

Comment: Looking at the manual, it looks like it sends a `LF` at the end of a reading. Note also that you don't *have* to use the `DataReceived` event. You could just use [SerialPort.ReadLine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.readline(v=vs.110).aspx) which will read up to the next newline character. So after your `Write` you could just `ReadLine`.

Comment: Final note: In your original code you are attaching a *new* `DataReceivedHandler` for *every single reading*. That's not a good idea. For the first reading, when data is received, you will execute `DataReceivedHandler` once. For the second reading it will execute *twice*. For the third reading *three times*, and so on. Obviously this will cause you a bunch of problems too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't bother with the `DataReceived` event here. You are sending a command to get a reading and then you can wait on the result by calling `ReadLine`. So I'd just do this:

```
mySerialPort.Open();    // Note: you don't need to keep opening the port!
while(true) {
    mySerialPort.Write(final);    // You didn't need the \n\r here either
    var reading = mySerialPort.ReadLine();
    // Do whatever processing you need to to extract an actual value
    Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue...");
    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.ReadKey();  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Reread the manual of your device

Structure your code as follows:

Have a private byte buffer for received bytes.

Whenever the serial port sends something, add it to the buffer.

If the buffer contains an 'end of transmission' character (for example a newline) parse the buffer's contents.

Comment: Thank u. Ur answer enlightened me about something. I could optimized my code now